# Use ScrollMagic (or other library) in Asp Spa Template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, webpack, scrollmagic

I use the ASP .Net SPA Template to develop a new website. This is the first time I try it in this way. 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/
(**Aurelia and Webpack**)

Now i like to use ScrollMagic on one site. But I don't get it. I took ScrollMagic over NPM and imported it in the correct file (**Typescript**) but VS say he can not found the class ScrollMagic.

How is the correct way to use a new Library like ScrollMagic in my Project?

```
import 'scrollmagic';

export class start {

     constructor() {
        var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
     }

     redirectStart(): void {
        location.href = "./#/counter"
     }
}
```

http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/section_wipes_manual.html

Thank you!